PowerShell 7 stream output of curl when using ConvetFrom-JSON
I use this command to get an Ollama completion via the WebUI API, using curl:
curl -sd '{"model": "code-companion:latest", "prompt": "Why is the sky blue?"}' http://127.0.0.1:11434/api/generate | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {Write-Host -NoNewline $_.response}

While this works great, it doesn't stream the output but displays the entire response at once.
If I don't use ConvertFrom-Json, then the curl output is indeed streamed.
How can I make ConvertFrom-Json stream the output?
This is what the curl stream returns:
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.2389913Z","response":"The","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.2630137Z","response":" sky","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.2866365Z","response":" appears","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.3095894Z","response":" blue","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.3322541Z","response":" because","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.3569029Z","response":" sun","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.3795768Z","response":"light","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.4033648Z","response":" reflect","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.4266986Z","response":"s","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.4492577Z","response":" off","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.4725215Z","response":" the","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.4951668Z","response":" Earth","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.5185997Z","response":"'s","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.5412377Z","response":" at","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.5643616Z","response":"mosphere","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.5877037Z","response":".","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.6106898Z","response":" The","done":false}


It would help to see a sample response and the desired output. You're writing $_.response, is this really the property you want to use? Using a similar command works for me: curl -s "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object { Write-Host -NoNewline $_.name }

@RuiJarimba The output is described here: https://github.com/ollama/ollama/blob/main/docs/api.md#response
I want to display the AI response, just the text, not the JSON, so I only output the response value.
Everything is displayed at once, if I remove convertfrom-json and write-host, I can see the streaming output.

@RuiJarimba It's hard to tell for your example, because that request finished immediately. But the completion request can take 10-15 seconds, and this script outputs only at the end. I want it to output each individual response, so you can see the completion in real-time as with ChatGPT

I think ConvertFrom-Json expects the entire response before it can convert it to a PowerShell object. Try moving it inside the ForEach-Object, something like: ForEach-Object { ConvertFrom-Json | Write-Host ...

This seems to do streaming: curl -sd $data $url |  % { if ($_ -match '"response":\s*"(.+?)"') {Write-Host -NoNewline $Matches[1]} } Were I just to regex match for the response, instead of ConvertFrom-Json

@RuiJarimba That is not valid syntax: cmdlet ConvertFrom-Json at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for the following parameters: InputObject:

curl is an alias for Invoke-WebRequest (see: Get-Command Curl), this cmdlet returns a single json string meaning that even if you would able to stream your json (which might be a complex object graph in contrast to a flat list of properties), the stream is already choked at the first cmdlet (which will pile up everything in memory anyways).

@iRon I am not sure what you mean. If I just use curl (IWR), I can see the output being streamed. The Ollama API returns a stream of JSON objects. The problem is that ConvertFrom-JSON buffers the output.

The answer I posted does work, but I don't feel too comfortable using a regex match for parsing the output (less robust, harder to update in the future). I wanted to know if there's any way to use proper JSON objects while the output is being streamed.

The documentation link you posted says the response contains "A stream of JSON objects" which sounds like multiple concatenated json documents. Could you add a sample response to your question so we can see what that looks like?

@mclayton I added a curl stream output example

In that case you probably want to swap the ConvertTo-Json/ForEach-Object  cmdlets. Something like: curl -sd '{"model": "code-companion:latest", "prompt": "Why is the sky blue?"}' http://127.0.0.1:11434/api/generate | ForEach-Object { ConvertFrom-Json $_ } | Write-Host ...

@iRon That doesn't work:
Line |   11 |  … ch-Object { ConvertFrom-Json $_ } | Write-Host -NoNewline $_.response      |                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      | The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the      | parameters that take pipeline input.

So far it looks like ConvertFrom-Json will always buffer the output no matter what.
I found a work-around, filtering the JSON output using Regex, using a -match operation. This seems to stream intermediary output (still has some buffering, but does streaming instead of displaying everything at once):
curl -sd $data $url | % { 
    if ($_ -match '"response":\s*"(.+?)"') {Write-Host -NoNewline $Matches[1]} 
}

I used an if statement, otherwise the -match would constantly output True.

The response looks like it's a series of multiple json documents concatenated into a single response stream. Your current approach waits until it's received the entire response stream and then converts it to json.
One json document per line
As an alternative, as long as the response is "one json document per line" you could do what @iron suggests in the comments.
First, we'll se up some test data:
$responseLines = @"
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.2389913Z","response":"The","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.2630137Z","response":" sky","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.2866365Z","response":" appears","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.3095894Z","response":" blue","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.3322541Z","response":" because","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.3569029Z","response":" sun","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.3795768Z","response":"light","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.4033648Z","response":" reflect","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.4266986Z","response":"s","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.4492577Z","response":" off","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.4725215Z","response":" the","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.4951668Z","response":" Earth","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.5185997Z","response":"'s","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.5412377Z","response":" at","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.5643616Z","response":"mosphere","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.5877037Z","response":".","done":false}
{"model":"code-companion:latest","created_at":"2024-04-09T15:12:51.6106898Z","response":" The","done":false}
"@ -split "`n"

Then we can process it with foreach-object { ($_ | convertfrom-json).response }. (The following sample code will stream response lines with a short pause between them so you can simulate delays in the api response).
$responseLines `
    | foreach-object {
        # output the response lines with a short delay between them to
        # simulate delays from the api
        write-output $_; start-sleep -milliseconds 250
    } `
    | foreach-object {
        ($_ | convertfrom-json).response
    }

You should now see output in the console for each response line in real(ish)-time as it arrives...
Note the first foreach-object isn't needed in your production code - it's just there to inject a delay in the pipeline between each response line being processed so you can see the output is streaming.
Multi-line json documents
If the json output is formatted across multiple lines per the documentation (see https://github.com/ollama/ollama/blob/main/docs/api.md#response), e.g.
{
  "model": "llama2",
  "created_at": "2023-08-04T08:52:19.385406455-07:00",
  "response": "The",
  "done": false
}

then you'll need to do a bit more work - you can basically accumulate the response lines until they form a valid json document and then process them.
Here's some test data again:
$responseLines = @"
{
    "model":      "code-companion:latest",
    "created_at": "2024-04-09T15:12:51.2389913Z",
    "response":   "The",
    "done":       false
}
{
    "model":      "code-companion:latest",
    "created_at": "2024-04-09T15:12:51.2630137Z",
    "response":   " sky",
    "done":       false
}
{
    "model":      "code-companion:latest",
    "created_at": "2024-04-09T15:12:51.2866365Z",
    "response":   " appears",
    "done":       false
}
"@ -split "`n"

and the code to process it:
$responseLines `
    | foreach-object {
        # output the response lines with a short delay between them to
        # simulate delays from the api
        write-output $_; start-sleep -milliseconds 250
    } `
    | foreach-object `
        -begin   {
            $buffer = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList;
        } `
        -process {
        $null = $buffer.Add($_);
        try {
            $obj = $buffer | ConvertFrom-Json
            # the next lines only run if the buffer contains a
            # full, valid json document
            write-output $obj.response
            $buffer = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList;
        }
        catch {
        }
    }

(the first for-each can be omitted again for the same reason - it's just injecting a delay into the pipeline between items)
